# Font for programming source code with LaTeX

Tags: latex, listings

Listing style is normally used for source code listing, but to me the default font used is not  so pretty for source code listing. Attached is a comparison between listing and verbatim.

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/8906/screenshot20100717at115.png

- How can I use the font for verbatim when I use listing environment?
- What would be a good font for source code listing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree the defaults of listings aren't that appealing. Usually I write something like

```
\lstset{columns=fullflexible,basicstyle=\ttfamily}
```

You might also need to play around with the `identifierstyle`, `commentstyle`, etc., keys if the style for your code uses these separately.

The `columns=fullflexible` keyval suppresses listings's layout thing that it does to make proportional-width text fit into a monospace grid; it's not necessary if you choose a monospace font to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try \texttt? It's the teletypefont family, a fixed-width font. It should look better.